# EC2 Scheduler - add additional templates

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, scheduler

Is there a way to add additional templates to the 'default' EC2 scheduler https://aws.amazon.com/answers/infrastructure-management/ec2-scheduler/

so say i want two separate functions/tags
start VM @ 8am on a weekday
stop VM @ 8pm on a weekday

There's a bit of confusion where I work with VMs not starting up because we only have a stopVM schedule, and custom start tag values are being setup wrong or not at all

going by the doco it seems like i need to set up one or the other (or a single instance that starts and stops VMs) 
then use custom values in the individual tags of the VMs to assign a custom value to the start or stop time

but i want something simpler
eg add Ec2Scheduler:startAt8 - true
Ec2Scheduler:StopAt8 - true

do i need to have 2 instances of the scheduler running or can i add another row to the DynamoDB db?

The doco.pdf is not very good at explaining this.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use tool that have simple scheduler like [CloudTiming](https://cloudtiming.com), but unfortunately it's not free but pretty cheap. You can setup schedule for any resources in any region. From my perspective Amazon's interface is not so user-friendly for such simple action.